# How do we add DNS servers to our VPN network definitions?

Tags: vpn, dns

I just set up a VPN connection to my workplace, but it fail s to connect.  Our protocol for setting up VPN on Windows clients requires we specify DNS servers that are inside our corporate network.  I cannot find the way to do this on Ubuntu f.or the VPN connection I have set up.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried this but it may help you. [From the Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/serverguide.pdf)

> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz /etc/openvpn/  
> sudo gzip -d /etc/openvpn/server.conf.gz
> ```
>
> Edit `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` changing the following options to:
>
> ```
> local 172.18.100.101
> dev tap0
> up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"
> down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"
> ;server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
> server-bridge 172.18.100.101 255.255.255.0 172.18.100.105 172.18.100.200
> push "route 172.18.100.1 255.255.255.0"
> push "dhcp-option DNS 172.18.100.20"
> push "dhcp-option DOMAIN example.com"
> tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
> ```
>
> Then
>
> ```
> cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
> source vars
> ./pkitool hostname
> ```
>
> Replace hostname with the actual hostname of the machine connecting to the VPN.
>   Copy the following files to the client:
>
> ```
> /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/hostname.crt
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/hostname.key
> /etc/openvpn/ta.key
> ```